# EF Serialize: ICollection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, xml-serialization, icollection

I am working on EF and I would like to serialize the records in the database and deseriailize back to display it at a console application.

Here's the 2 classes of the application:

```
[Serializable()]
public class Product : ISerializable
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string Productname { get; set; }
    public Decimal? UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public bool Discontinued { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    public Product() { }

    void ISerializable.GetObjectData(
        SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
    }
}

[Serializable()]
public class Category : ISerializable
{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public byte[] Picture { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }



    public Category() { }

    void ISerializable.GetObjectData(
        SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

I figured out that, this will lead to error as an interface cannot be serialized, that is Products in the Category class.

So, if I delete the line below which caused the error:

```
public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
```

The program will run successfully. ( Succeed to serialize and deserialize)

However, if I deleted this line, the lazyloading properties will be lost.

I would really like to keep the lazyloading property, could anyone suggest a solution for me. Thanks!

Comment: I just want to be clear, because there's some confusing things in here; EF would normally be used for *persistence*, but it **does not** use serialization; do you actually mean serialization here? i.e. are you storing this as a BLOB/CLOB in a single column? Or are you storing this in tables with columns per member? Secondly: if you are using serialization, which is it? You have tagged `xml-serialization`, but `ISerializable`/`[Serializable]` is `BinaryFormatter`, not xml; equally, your custom serialization implementations are empty... so: please clarify what exactly is going on?

Comment: (I should also observe that you haven't added a custom deserialization constructor, which is required when implementing `ISerializable`; all in all, it makes me strongly suspect that you have confused serialization and persistence, and that currently all the `[Serializable]` / `ISerializable` stuff is completely redundant and unused)

Comment: And you also didn't mention what error you have received

Comment: @LadislavMrnka The error is "Cannot serialize member Category.Products of type System.Collections.Generic.ICollection because it is an interface.  So, if I delete the line I coded, my program ran successfully. However, the lazyloading property will be lost, if I got the idea correct by searching on the Net. So, I would like to know if there's any methods that can keep the lazyloading property.

Comment: @user1484319 please clarify: what serializer are you using? It sounds like you are using `XmlSerializer`, but: that **doesn't use** `ISerializable` or `[Serializable]`, and has nothing whatsoever to do with EF.